# Запятая в названии магазина

Tags: пунктуация

Есть у нас в городе то ли кафе, то ли магазин пива на разлив с замечательным названием "Расти(,) пузо".
Насколько я помню (вижу обычно это название мельком из окна маршрутки), запятой перед "пузом" там нет. А действительно, нужна она там или нет? С одной стороны, обращение к пузу, а с другой, вроде как и нет.

Comment: Я видел в Костроме пивную под названием "Дорогая, буду поздно". ))

Answer (score 3):

Без запятой это циничное обращение к потенциальному посетителю ("расти его, своё пузо"), ведь у нас рекламщики давно не церемонятся и обращаются к людям на "ты". Возможно, и намеренно хотели двусмысленность придать (казнить нельзя помиловать).

Answer (score 0):

И в смыле "отращивай" циничное отношение налицо, и в другом смысле, где адресат неодушевлён, запятая не столь нужна, сколько нужен знак восклицания.